# Should we start moving on-topic questions from SO and Serverfault to here?

Tags: discussion

Over the years many DevOps questions have been asked and sometimes even answered on the other common stackexchange sites.  Should we make a concerted effort to move those questions over here, or should we just wait for it to happen naturally when relevant?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unless dev ops questions are explicitly deemed off topic on those sites, we have no cause or right to remove content from another site… along with the reputation/ownership that goes with it.

Besides, the users who asked those questions aren't necessarily members on *this* site. The wholesale importing of content from elsewhere is not really a great way to build a new community. Questions imported from elsewhere would likely be orphaned if the author does not have an account here. The tags wouldn't match. They may not follow the posting guidelines here. And anonymous content always has that odd, back-dated feel of long-forgotten questions that no one really cares about any longer. If someone were to post another answer to one of those old threads, or even ask for a bit of followup, no one would receive the notification as they do now.

Essentially, we would be loading this site up with a lot of questions asked and answered a long time ago… without imparting any of the benefits of reputation, ownership, or experience into the community that is supposed to take care of it.

That is why we don't do that.

Answer (score 13):

No.

Sites can, and do, exist with overlapping scope. Migrating here, especially at this early state, is premature. We should let this site grow on it's own content.

Comment: what about unanswered DevOps questions? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392666/1800-unanswered-devops-questions-at-so